# Short story about a group of humans who can change the shape and makeup of their bodies and survive hostile environments

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space

I am unsure how they can change their body; it may be an implant or genetic manipulation. It was only a group of humans not all humanity. I believe it played mostly in space or other planets. The humans could withstand high heat or radiation by turning their bodies into balls or a similar extreme modification. But I believe some died or did not revert because they did not consider vital organs or important aspects of their transformation. I don't know if they had a human handler that kept contact with them or whether the story was written from the perspective of one of those humans.

I think I read it in the '90s. I am fairly certain that it is a short story. I read it in German.

Comment: Sounds like a passage from Ian McDonalds [Necroville](http://www.literatureireland.com/book/necroville-ian-mcdonald), just adding here to rule it out.

Comment: I remember a novel similar to this, but not the title. It began with a group of refugees fleeing in space with a creche of genetically improved babies. Knowing that they will soon be destroyed, the refugees hide the babies in life pods and set them adrift. The babies turn into crystal-like eggs, and those who are found decades later recover and mature, with some superhuman abilities. (Not abilities at the level of comic book heroes) The novel takes place within the solar system.

Comment: I'm thinking of Orson Scott Card's novel _[A Planet Called Treason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Planet_Called_Treason)_ (1979).

Comment: I had a rather lengthy conversation with ChatGPT on this topic before I asked here and I can rule out (but maybe these are of interest to others):

"The Thing from Another World" by John W. Campbell Jr.,
"Bloodchild" by Octavia Butler, "A Planet Named Shayol" by Cordwainer Smith, "The Giving Plague" by David Brin, "Beggars in Spain" by Nancy Kress,  "The Morphology of the Kirkham Wreck" by Hilbert Schenck, "Flatlander" by Larry Niven, "The Godwhale" by T.J. Bass.

Comment: The closest seems to be Flatlander where part of ChatGPT's summary goes like this: 

Shaeffer is one of the few humans who is able to withstand the pressure of the planet's atmosphere, thanks to his genetic modifications. However, he must use all of his training and concentration to remember which organs he has modified and to avoid accidentally changing his shape or losing control of his body.

The part about modification and avoiding accidentally making wrong modifications comes closest to the story I am looking for. However, in my story people could assume different shapes.